# App crashed, when I was trying to capture full-size photo by camera with api lower 21

Tags: java, android, camera

I’m testing Android sample from official documentation. And my app works fine with api 21 and higher, but always crashes with api lower than 21, as example KitKat (api 19). I'm not using camera directly, only via other app (make and send Intent).
My current appcompat lib: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2`

How I could resolve this problem?

Found solution here:
https://medium.com/@a1cooke/using-v4-support-library-fileprovider-and-camera-intent-a45f76879d61

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

LogCat here:

```
    01-29 15:51:14.414 3090-3090/com.android.camera D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1632/system_process W/AudioService: onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
01-29 15:51:14.414 3090-3090/com.android.camera W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d75b20)
01-29 15:51:14.414 1573-1915/system_process W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{a538ebb8 3090:com.android.camera/u0a32} (pid=3090, uid=10032) that is not exported from uid 10057
01-29 15:51:14.414 3090-3090/com.android.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.android.camera, PID: 3090
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{a538ebb8 3090:com.android.camera/u0a32} (pid=3090, uid=10032) that is not exported from uid 10057
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2848)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4415)
                                                                      at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2207)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1425)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:906)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
                                                                      at com.android.camera.Camera.doAttach(Camera.java:1385)
                                                                      at com.android.camera.Camera.onReviewDoneClicked(Camera.java:1362)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Simple code here:

```
<application>
   ...
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
    ...
</application>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ...
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}




private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: "but always crushes with api lower than 21" -- there is no Java stack trace in your LogCat snippet in your question. You need to find the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: have added stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to `takePictureIntent`. As it stands, the camera app has no rights to work with that `Uri`.

See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider) for a complete implementation of using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`.